# Appending rows to empty DataFrame not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a piece of Python code that essentially reduces to the following:

```
import pandas as pd

months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
l = [1607.8, 1688.17, 1605.66, 1469.03, 1312.65, 1451.74, 1445.26, 1350.94, 1371.27, 1201.6, 1240.59, 1291.43]

# First, construct a empty DataFrame.
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = months, dtype=float)

# Then, keep adding rows to DataFrame given by list l.
df.append([l])

print df
```

Expected output is:

```
      Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May      Jun      Jul      Aug  \
0  1607.8  1688.17  1605.66  1469.03  1312.65  1451.74  1445.26  1350.94   

       Sep     Oct      Nov      Dec  
0  1371.27  1201.6  1240.59  1291.43
```

However what I get is the following:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec]
Index: []
```

If I replace `df.append([l])` with the following, things work fine for me.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([l], columns = months)
df.columns = months
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10):

You should use [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to add a row given a list `l`:

```
df.loc[len(df.index)+1] = l
```

The method [`pd.DataFrame.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) is used to append one dataframe, or other appendable object, to an existing dataframe:

> DataFrame.append(*other, ignore_index=False, verify_integrity=False, sort=None*)
>
> Append rows of other to the end of this frame

---

However, it is more efficient to form a list of lists and then call `pd.DataFrame.append` just once.

```
list_of_lists = []

for item in some_iterable:
    l = foo(item)
    list_of_lists.append(l)

df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(list_of_lists, columns=df.columns))
```

The reason for this is `list.append` is cheaper than `pd.DataFrame.loc` assignment.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you (the second method with a single df.append)!

Answer (score 6):

`pd.append()` does not happen in place. You need to save the output in order to use it.

Comment: That was my original mistake which led me here :)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way:

```
   df= pd.DataFrame(l).T
   df.columns=months
```

Answer (score 0):

For constructing the dataframe with the data of `l` already in place, this is probably best:

```
pd.DataFrame([l], columns=months)
```

For appending a row to the existing dataframe via the `append` method, this works:

```
df.append(pd.DataFrame([l], columns=months))
```

For appending a row in general, the suggestion made by [jpp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9209546/jpp) is probably best.

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the columns doesn't matter, you can just use this one line:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(months,l)),index=[0])
```

Output:

```
Apr      Aug      Dec      Feb     Jan      Jul      Jun      Mar  \
0  1469.03  1350.94  1291.43  1688.17  1607.8  1445.26  1451.74  1605.66   

       May      Nov     Oct      Sep  
0  1312.65  1240.59  1201.6  1371.27
```

If you want to order the columns by the order of the months, then just add this line after the data frame is constructed:

```
df = df[months]
```

Output:

```
Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May      Jun      Jul      Aug  \
0  1607.8  1688.17  1605.66  1469.03  1312.65  1451.74  1445.26  1350.94   

       Sep     Oct      Nov      Dec  
0  1371.27  1201.6  1240.59  1291.43
```